# Is it correct to write "buy with credit card"?

Tags: phrase-choice

For the verb "pay", it is correct to use "*pay with/by credit card*", according to the Cambridge Business English Dictionary and also according to English in Use by Raymond Murphy. So, what about the verb "buy"? Is it correct to write "*buy something with a credit card*"? I looked for exemplary sentences in Oxford Learner's Dictionary, Cambridge Dictionary, lexico.com and LDOCE, but I haven't found a sentence with "*...buy with a credit card*".

Comment: The sequence [*buy with a credit card*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22buy+with+a+credit+card%22) occurs at least hundreds of times in Google Books. And [here it is](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buy+with+a+credit+card&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuy%20with%20a%20credit%20card%3B%2Cc0) in Google Ngrams, too. Where did you look? Was it accidental that you didn't include the article *(**a**)* in the question title here, but you *did* include it in the question text itself?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "buy something with a credit card" is natural English. Equally common (at least here in Canada), is, "buy something **on** a credit card".

Here are some natural English examples I found:

> If you’re in a rush to buy that new washing machine, you might be able to **buy it with a credit card**... --[Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/advisor/2019/11/03/five-ways-to-buy-something-you-cant-afford/?sh=471e84d646c6)
>
> As an example, if an item has a one-year warranty, and you **bought it with a credit card**, there’s a good chance your credit card will add one extra year of coverage—for free. --[CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2014/11/12/best-credit-cards-to-extend-your-warranty-coveragefor-free.html)
>
> Most teens (51%) agree that it is easier to **buy things with a credit card** than cash. --[CBS News](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/should-kids-be-playing-with-credit-cards/)